# SQL query to show grouped rows in columns

Tags: sql

Query:

```
SELECT ProductId,LanguageId,FileType 
FROM dbo.ProductFile
GROUP BY ProductId,FileType,LanguageId
```

Result:

```
===============================
| Code | Language | File Type |
-------------------------------
| 2040 | English  | manual    |
| 2040 | English  | exploded  |
| 2040 | English  | catalog   |
| 2040 | Dutch    | catalog   |
| 2041 | English  | manual    |
| 2041 | English  | exploded  |
| 2041 | Dutch    | catalog   |
| 2041 | Dutch    | manual    |
===============================
```

Target: Show each product in each language in a row with each file type in a column

```
=================================================
| Code | Language | manual | exploded | catalog |
-------------------------------------------------
| 2040 | English  | true   | true     | true    |
| 2040 | Dutch    | false  | false    | true    |
| 2041 | English  | true   | true     | false   |
| 2041 | Dutch    | true   | false    | true    |
=================================================
```

Anyone has experienced please?

Comment: Can your share DBMS/database you're using and your best coding attempt at this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use conditional aggregation as the following:

```
SELECT Code, Language,
       MAX(CASE FileType WHEN 'manual' THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) manual,
       MAX(CASE FileType WHEN 'exploded' THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) exploded,
       MAX(CASE FileType WHEN 'catalog' THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) catalog
FROM ProductFile
GROUP BY Code, Language
ORDER BY Code, Language
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/EWngp24b).